# How to make two different tailwind configs in angular project?

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

For example, I have angular (v13) project, and this project contain several applications in angular.json (it different websites). Before, I can use custom-webpack. But now, when I have angular 13 and tailwind 3, i can't use custom-webpack anymore. How to make different tailwind-configs for each application in a angular-project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put `tailwind.config.js` per `projects/[project-name]/` and then in each of applications' `styles.css` you can add `@config "../tailwind.config.js";` at the top of the file.

Works with Angular 16 and Tailwind 3.

Comment: Could you please share sample, with above structure, I am trying to use the solution you have described, however the custom tailwindconfig is not getting picked up. I am using angular 16 and tailwindcss 3. I have created a workspace which has three projects, admin , webApp and common. I tried to add the tailwind config specific to webapp in the same level as  src folder and then in the styles.scss include the custom tailwindcss config file using the @config .

Comment: put it outside of src. configs should generally not go into src dir. you just need to correctly reference the file with appropriate relative path from `styles.css` to `tailwind.config.js`

Answer (score 1):

How about using Tailwind CLI to compile different configs and adding their output css to each individual application?

`npx tailwindcss -c ./tailwindcss-config.js -i input.css -o output.css`

Comment: Yep, as an option) but still I would like to do everything beautifully with angular

Comment: FYI, Nx.dev build system supports multiple Tailwind CSS configurations and it has an easy generator for setup: https://nx.dev/l/a/angular/setup-tailwind. That generator basically adds Tailwind related imports to target application's src/styles.css and adds an empty tailwind.config.js to application root directory. This makes me think that it should not be too hard to do this in your environment?